# VBA in Access: Prompt for input to select report to print

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am working with an Access database and have VBA I've written for a user to update a database and then print the resulting report to PDF.  I now want to allow an option to print one of two reports, depending on which one the user selects to run.

I know I will have to prompt for user input, ideally via drop-down list (which I haven't figured out how to do, but Google seems to indicate it's do-able).  My question is how to get the code to execute the open report based on what the input is.

I have two thoughts about this - I can either write it all in VBA where the printed report depends on what is selected, or the prompt can be tied to run one of two macros that will then execute the report.  Any advice on how to write the code to allow for user input would be appreciated - or if I'm thinking about this totally backwards, I'd appreciate any alternate suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input box to ask the user to select a number to reference a report.  Example of how to accomplish this is below.

```
Dim iAnswer

iAnswer = InputBox("Enter in the number of the report you want to run" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "1) ReportName1" & vbCrLf & "2) ReportName2")
    If iAnswer = 1 Then
        'run macro to produce report 1
    Else
        If iAnswer = 2 Then
            'run macro to produce report 2
        Else
            MsgBox "Not a valid report selection"
        End If
    End If
```